# php email headers with MIME-Version: 1.0

Tags: php, email, header, mime

I have these lines of code:

```
        $from = "email@domian.com";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

I need the MIME type because I am using file_get_contents for an html file, my problem is under the headers it displays as "email@domain.comMIME-Version:1.0" and I want it just to say "email@domain.com" how do I take out the MIME type in the from displaying in the header?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `\r\n` after the `From:` header as well.

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$to = "whereyousendmail@gmail.com";
$from = "email@domian.com";
$subject = "New Agent Record";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: New Agent Record <email@domian.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path:New Agent Record <email@domian.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "From: New Agent Record <email@domian.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Organization: Your Email Subject\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
```

Comment: does your answer anything different from the one already given... you could have voted that up also

Comment: Thanks! I like the list of header details that you added @Hafiz Uzman